# Jest - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, angular-test

I can see there are lots of questions about this on SO but none of them answer my problem.

I have the following test

```
 it('will poll until there are no subscribers', () => {
    const polls: string[] = [];
    const complete = new Subject<void>();
    const observableSub = service
      .getPollData()
      .pipe(takeUntil(complete))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        polls.push(value);
        if (polls.length === 3) {
          console.log('here ' + JSON.stringify(polls));
          observableSub.unsubscribe();
          complete.next();
          complete.complete();
        }
      });

    return complete.toPromise().then(() => {
      console.log(service.isPolling);
      expect(service.isPolling).toEqual(false);
    });
  });
```

When the test runs both of my console logs are present and have the correct expected values. This all happens within 20ms, my poll frequency is set at just 5ms for the test.

I have looked at every SO post I can find, I have tried using `async`, `async(done) => done()`, `fakeAsync` and nothing seems to work. I always get the following error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

NB : I am injecting a `MockInterceptor` for the responses and the service is using RxJs `timer()` observable for the polling, I can confirm that this is closed and unsubscribed at then end of the test, this is confirmed by the `expect(service.isPolling)` line of code. I have tried using `jest.userRealTimers` and `jest.useFakeTimers` in case this was part of the issue, but the fact that my console logs show the expected values makes me think this is not the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

*Update as suggested by @Estus Flask I have updated the code now to this:

```
it('will poll until there are no subscribers', async () => {
      const polls: any[] = [];
      const observableSub = service.getPollData().pipe(
      take(3),
      tap((value) => {
        polls.push(value);
      })
    );
      await observableSub.toPromise().then(() => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(polls));
      console.log(service.isPolling);
      expect(service.isPolling).toEqual(false);
    });
 });
```

But still getting the same error, feel I am doing/missing something simple and stupid ?!?!? NB: Console outputs are still all correct.

Comment: Observables interact in a clumsy way and errors aren't handled. `complete` is redundant, it's likely not competed and this results in pending promise, can't say why exactly. There should be only one observable, likely with `take(3)`, use toPromise on it. and `await` it.

Comment: @Estus Flask thanks for the suggestion, I have changed to as you suggested (I think) still getting the same error :/ very frustrating.

Comment: take(3) results in completed observable and is converted to a resolved promise so it cannot cause this error. Then the explanation is that there's less than 3 values, or the error refers to another block, not necessarily `it`.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes as I mentioned, all console output is the expected values, including the 3 polls, service.isPolling == false, it's very odd. I'm confident the service has cleaned up it's RxJsTimer and is unsubscribed also

Comment: @EstusFlask, solved, see my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this issue, its worth taking a look at your other tests in the test set.

Turned out that for me the above test was passing fine, however a subsequent test with a setTimeout was failing. This was confusing Jest which was then marking the passing test as failed!

I lost a LOT of time on this, so hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using done?

```
it('will poll until there are no subscribers', async (done) => {
      const polls: any[] = [];
      const observableSub = service.getPollData().pipe(
      take(3),
      tap((value) => {
        polls.push(value);
      })
    );
      await observableSub.toPromise().then(() => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(polls));
      console.log(service.isPolling);
      expect(service.isPolling).toEqual(false);
      done()
    });
 });
```